# Le « standing/stand-up desk » et le « sit-stand/sit to stand/«sit/stand»/sit n' stand/riser/rise up/adjustable height desk » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, choix-de-mot

> A **standing desk** or **stand-up desk** is a desk conceived for
> writing, reading or drawing while standing up or while sitting on a
> high stool. ([*Standing desk*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_desk), Wikipédia)

...*qui a été conçu pour écrire, lire ou dessiner debout ou assis sur un tabouret*. Et là on trouve aussi le *sit-stand/sit to stand/«sit/stand»/sit n' stand desk*, qui permet l'une ou l'autre station, et tout un vocable plus ou moins synonyme (*riser/rise up desk, adjustable height desk*) quand le modèle dispose d'attributs variables.

[image]
<sup><sup>[*Standing desk illustration*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_desk#/media/File:Standing_desk_illustration.svg) ; illustration de Mattthew Brauer basée sur une photo de Angus McIntyre, CC BY-SA 3.0</sup></sup>

Comment le nomme-t-on en français ? Premièrement s'agit-il généralement d'un *bureau*, d'un *pupitre* ou d'une *station/table de travail* ? Deuxièmement, suffit-il d'ajouter [*debout*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/debout) et peut-on confirmer si c'est l'adverbe ou l'adjectif, ce dernier signifiant *qui n'est pas couché* (Wiktionnaire) ; et incidemment comment marquera-t-on le pluriel ? Troisièmement, est-on capable d'évoquer le lexique du changement de station et des propriétés variables de certains modèles en intégrant ce qui précède ; finalement pourquoi a-t-on ou non un lexique clair, précis et systématique pour décrire ce dont il s'agit ?

Comment: Bureaux assis-debout, bureaux debout, bureaux hauts...

Answer (score 3):

On peut trouver le terme *bureau debout*, ou *bureau assis/debout* (pour un meuble qui peut s'adapter aux deux positions).

*Debout* me semble alors plutôt un adverbe en apposition qu'un adjectif épithète (ce n'est pas le bureau qui est debout, mais son utilisateur qui travaille debout, a fortiori aussi pour *bureau assis/debout*. C'est un cas proche de *mange-debout*, bien que là ce soit un verbe qui est utilisé).

*Debout* étant de toute manière invariable même quand utilisé comme adjectif, on écrira *des bureaux debout*.

Exemple: https://www.jobat.be/fr/art/voici-les-7-bureaux-debout-les-plus-cools

Comment: Merci ! Est-ce que ta formulation _meuble qui peut s'adapter aux deux positions_ implique que _ajustable_ est plutôt inutile pour toi et que tu dis _adaptable_ à la place ?

Answer (score 2):

En complément à la réponse de Greg, pour la première question, sur base d'une rapide recherche Google, on trouve les termes suivants, par ordre décroissant d'occurrences:

- ***bureau réglable*** (221k)
- ***bureau réglable en hauteur*** (119k)
- ***bureau debout*** (86k)
- ***station assis debout*** (80k)
- ***bureau assis debout*** (60k)
- ***bureau ajustable*** (58k)
- *bureau debout assis* (28k)
- *poste debout* (16k)
- *poste assis debout* (12k)
- *bureau ajustable en hauteur* (11k)
- *station de travail assis debout* (8k)
- *station de travail debout* (4k)
- *station debout assis* (3.6k)

(Note: pour les occurrences de "assis debout" et "debout assis", elles incluent aussi les versions avec un tiret (*assis-debout*), fréquentes, ou avec une barre oblique (*assis/debout*), plus rares.)

*Pupitre* correspond à meuble différent (le support haut et incliné où l'on pose un livre ou des notes pour un exposé réalisé debout, ou une petite table d'écolier), et n'est normalement pas utilisé dans ce sens-ci.

*Station debout* est théoriquement possible, mais est déjà utilisé par la référence à la position du corps (*la station debout*, *la station assise*) et donc est à éviter ici.

EDIT: ajout des expressions mentionnées par mouviciel (*bureau réglable*, etc.), qui s'avèrent effectivement les plus utilisées.

Comment: Bonne nuance pour la _station_ ! La recherche des termes sur le web permet d'illustrer mais j'ai peur que parfois les termes y apparaissent davantage pour fins d'optimisation de recherche (multiplier les _hits_) que parce que ce serait usuel.

Comment: @ilsuffit Bon point, et il faut prendre les résultats de ce type avec des pincettes, le plus gros risque étant de confondre des usages différents (si ne voit pas l'autre sens de _station debout_, on le donne premier à 298k occurrences). L'optimisation web (SEO) joue probablement un rôle, mais surtout en exagérant les scores des mots rares (impression d'usage alors que jamais utilisés). Elle devrait gonfler tous les termes de manière équivalente, donc l'ordre devrait rester le même, et les premiers restent valides.

Comment: C'est noté, merci !

Answer (score 2):

Pour les bureaux qui peuvent s'ajuster, les termes consacrés par les vendeurs de mobilier de bureau sont **bureau réglable en hauteur** ou bien **bureau assis debout**, voir par exemple ce que donne un moteur de recherche avec les mots: [bureau ajustable](https://www.google.com/search?q=bureau+ajustable).

Quant au mobilier fixe, je ne connais pas de bureau à proprement parler. Il y a bien les **tables hautes** ou bien les **mange-debout**, mais c'est plus pour la cuisine que pour le travail.

Comment: Merci ! Peut-être une autre question pour savoir lequel de réglable, ajustable ou adaptable est l'adjectif le plus usuel pour introduire la possibilité des deux utilisations.

Comment: En cherchant _ajustable_ les résultats orientaient vers _réglable_. Sinon plus généralement, pour moi _réglable_ et _ajustable_ diffèrent surtout par l'étendue et la précision de la modification: un réglage est plus large et moins précis, un ajustement est plus réduit et plus précis. Quant à _adaptable_, je dirais que c'est une modification d'une ampleur plus importante qu'un simple réglage et qu'on réalise une fois pour toutes.

Comment: Bon point sur "bureau réglable en hauteur". En l'ajoutant à ma comparaison de fréquences, c'est effectivement le plus utilisé avec _bureau réglable_.